Can not copy shortcuts in C:/ProgramData, Windows 10 Pro
These shortcuts C:/ProgramData appear to be hard links or system variables.
I moved the Program files, Program Files(x86) and ProgramData to a separate drive. I kept the originals on the OS C: drive. But I can't copy the shortcuts of each file.
I do this to separate third party apps and control the growth of the OS.  Been doing this for a long time but lost all my notes and it has been years since I did this the last time.
I can make shortcuts for the shortcuts but that is improper.
Need to make copies of Application Data, Desktop, Documents, Start menu, & Templates to put on new drive.

You should not do this, to begin with. While it's OK to move user profile folders, and mechanisms are built in to the OS to allow this, changing the location of Program Data and Program Files has never been a supported or recommended configuration. For many programs you can specify the install directory during installation, and this is actually supported and means you don't need to do any of the OS-breaking things you're trying.
